# Problem buy using Catalog Price Rules

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, special-price, flat-catalog, product-prices

Set catalog prices with date in future.

The special price will be deleted after 2-3 days in the product data (all rules regarding) , although the date is not yet reached.

problem strikes with flat data and without.

Using Magento 1.9.0.1

Comment: Do not forgot to reindex data after save product and rules.

Comment: which indexers specifically?

Comment: check cron job is working or not , also you can reindex all indexcers once....